# Having trouble escaping characters in ansible variable "("

Tags: shell, ansible, aix

I'm encountering some weird issues with unexpected '('.

I have an ansible task

```yaml
- name: save results to csv
  become: yes
  shell: |
    res=$(istat "{{ var_path }}" | grep Protection | xargs)
    echo "\"{{ policyname }}\",\"{{ itemId }}\",\"{{ description }}\",\"$res\"" >> output.csv
```

this task works properly for most inputs. But when the description variable contains something like this :

"blah blah do this and that (something) something"

I get an error:

```
"std_err": "/bin/sh[3]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 3: `(' is not expected."
```

this only happens for values of `{{ description }}` that contain "()". When I try removing those characters, everything works fine.
If it matters, the target host is aix 7.1

Comment: Most likely, you have performed a successfull "shell-injection" attack against yourself. You should check if ansible offers some escaping feature.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `shell` module to append to a file, you should use the [lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html):

```yaml
- name: get what you need
  become: yes
  shell: 'istat "{{ var_path }}" | grep Protection | xargs'
  register: res

- name: insert it at the end of CSV
  lineinfile:
    line: '"{{ policyname }}","{{ itemId }}","{{ description }}","{{ res.stdout }}"'
    path: '/root/output.csv'
  become: yes
```

You can use the `regexp` parameter to make sure you don't insert the line into the file if it is already there if you want that. (Check documentation mentioned above)